# Unable to retrieve Json data from remote server binding to object in asp.net mvc

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, httprequest, webclient

I am developing an Asp.Net mvc application. In my application, I need to retrieve json object from remote server. I am using web client for it. But it is giving me error. My scenario is below.

I have this url

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{fb_id}/picture?width=200&height=200&redirect=false
```

When I access from browser, it return something like this

[image]

So I am trying to retrieve that data as json and then serialize them back. So I builds two classes like below to bind that data.

```
public class FacebookAvatarResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public FacebookAvatarData Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class FacebookAvatarData
    {
        [JsonProperty("height")]
        public int Height { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("width")]
        public int Width { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("is_silhouette")]
        public bool IsSilhouette { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
```

In controll, I built an action method

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
        public JsonResult Test(string avatarDataUrl)
        {
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                string data = webClient.DownloadString(avatarDataUrl);
                return Json(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookAvatarResponse>(data),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

As you can see I am getting that data as json and then return as action result. But when I request that action method passing correct url as parameter, it is giving me this error.

[image]

How can I retrieve JSON data from remote server binding to the specific classes?

Comment: if you remove `avatarDataUrl` and replace with `webClient.DownloadString("http://graph.facebook.com/{fb_id}/picture?width=200&height=200&redirect=false");` does it work?

Comment: Ya. It is working. It is downloading image directly. It is not returning Json instead like I access in browser. Why?

Comment: So is that working a expected or were you trying to return the JSON?

Comment: I just got it now. But I found another issue with it. It is downloading image when I access from browser. But when I request from another clients like android device, it is throwing error. I will post another question soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly your are not passing JSON to DeserializeObject.

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` takes JSON value.

Check your data should be in json format to deserialize.

```
Json(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookAvatarResponse>(data),
     JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```